# create an auto increment column which isn't a primary key

Tags: mysql, create-table

I read a lot about why this is a bad idea but here is why I want to do this.  I want my table to look like this:

```
id   |   article   |   link   |   text_cont
 1   |   //text    |   www... |  parsed text content
 2   |   //text2   |   www..2 |  parsed text content2
```

And so on.  The reson why I don't want my id to be the primary key is because I want my LINK to be the primary key...that way when I run a Cron Job to get more data, I will not have duplicate fields in my table.  I can use INSERT IGNORE and it will not include same links twice.  But I still want id to auto increment so I can use the "infinite scroll" using the id's.

Is this possible to do?  I really hope so because I think this is a good reason to have this...

Comment: To be honest, I'd still make `id` the primary key, and would make `link` an alternate key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_key#Alternate_key

Comment: I would just mark link as unique and it will not duplicate my entries?

Answer (score 1):

You cant auto-increment a text field.

Also if you don't want Id as your key, why do you want id? It seems like you need to change the way you run your cron job, not your schema

--

If you still want to know how to create an AI field:

```
link_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

And for existing data:

```
ALTER TABLE articles MODIFY COLUMN link_id int(4) auto_increment
```

Comment: I wrote that I want an auto incremented id to be able to run an infinite scroll, like a "load more" button.  I still want id to be an int and so it autoincrements

Comment: Then ID really seems like all you need still and have a unique constraint on the link? If you are expecting a lot of rows with URL's where only part changes I'd also consider just storing the part that changes, not www. etc. to keep the database size dowm

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it to work.  Keeping id as primary and putting unique on link doesn't duplicate entries.  This is great and easy because I saw other posts where people made second temporary tables just to get rid of duplicates.  This is so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a primary key to be able to have it auto increment. This works fine.

```
create table dude (
  id int auto_increment,
  link varchar(255),
  primary key (link),
  unique key (id)
);

insert into dude values (null, "www.google.com");
insert into dude values (null, "www.stackoverflow.com");
insert into dude values (null, "www.google.com");
```

It might not be the best table design but it answers your question.